# How to modify shipping options price dynamically in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

I need modify cost of shipping options depending on what is inside my cart/order.
The cost must be calculated on cart page and checkout page and of course save when order completed.

This is what I've done but it seems it has no effect, could someone has an idea please ?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates','over_cost',100,2);
function over_cost($rates,$package) {

global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
$qty=0;

        foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
            $_product = $values['data']->post; 
            $qty= $qty + $values['quantity']; 
          } 


    foreach ($rates as $rate) {

     if ($rate->cost=='flat_rate:4') {$rate->cost = 5*$qty;}


    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Comment: Did you check if you are getting "flat_rate:4" in request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates','test_overwrite_fedex',100,2);
    function test_overwrite_fedex($rates,$package) {

        foreach ($rates as $rate) {

            //Set the price
            $rate->cost = 1000;

            //Set the TAX
            $rate->taxes[1] = 1000 * 0.2;

        }

        return $rates;
    }
```

The rates are cached by Woocommerce using the wordpress transient function. So when you're testing, make sure you change the item quantity so the package rates are updated correctly, or you can empty the cart each time you refresh:)

Comment: thanks , and this should work in cart page and checkout page ?

Comment: $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() should work in checkout page ?

Comment: and $rate->cost = 1000 will just affect the cost of current order ?

Comment: $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() should work in checkout page ? - Yes



$rate->cost = 1000 will just affect the cost of current order ? - Yes. Only current order